# Risks associated with developers using their own domain for development services

Tags: dns-domain, domain

We have some development and test environments using our canonical domain, e.g. dev.example.com. We also use some services from 3rd party providers that have obscure URLs like xjkhasdkjvhas.dns.ashdfb.3rdparty.io.

The canonical domain is maintained strictly by our sys admins.

Some services are not served on port 80 which means any new instances need to be opened on our company firewall. And also some of these services have dynamic IP which also causes our firewall to need updating/scripting.

To clean it all up I'd like our developers to manage DNS records for a domain we supply, e.g. ex.io. They can then standardise easily memorable names for services (dev.ex.io, test.ex.io, api.ex.io, etc.), create reverse proxies with certbot for dynamically changing services on obscure ports and also clean up our canonical DNS so it's only used for production services.

Are there any real risks associated with this? The only thing I can think of is a public domain will provide clues as to our company and what services lie behind the domain (but that's already an issue with dev.example.com). As long as developers don't use this domain for production services is there a problem with this approach?

Comment: That depends on how mature your developers are. Sooner or later, someone is going to use `https://yeet.datboi.is/lit/` as API endpoint in development.

Comment: Hi, we'll control what domains they have acces to, not allowing them to create their own domains

Comment: While not much of a security issue by itself, it suggests a very cavalier attitude from the developers, which can make it more likely that they'll also take shortcuts when it comes to security. It also suggests that you code isn't in centrally maintained repositories, which _is_ a security concern. One possible issue is, the 3rd party DNS providers could point the domains to any arbitrary IP address, intercepting traffic that was intended for your dev servers.

Comment: Edited for clarification, 3rd parties don't provide DNS services, they provide services we leverage at addresses under their control e.g. AWS, elastic.co.